# Statements number system, negating of a sentence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education

[image: Image Description]

*Why is my answer incorrect or why it must be equality symbol that is coming in?*

Comment: What is the negation of "a is greater than b"?

Comment: explanation in image is self explanatory for your question

Comment: so it shouldn't be just less than?

Answer (score 0):

"*If* $9>10$ *then* $3^2=5$" is the same as "$9\le 10$ *or* $3^2=5$".

If you say "$9$ is not greater than $10$", it means $9$ is either less than $10$ or it is equal to $10$, therefore $\sim(9>10)$ is the same as $9\not >10$ which is the same as $9\le 10$.

Comment: Thank you so much.